# Why do Palestinians want a one state solution?

Tags: israel, palestine

Apparently, Israel currently supports a two state solution at conditions that are unacceptable to the Palestinian Authority, but not worlds apart.

Palestinians, on the other hand, accept it merely [as a stepping stone towards a one state solution](http://www.jpost.com/Diplomacy-and-Politics/6-in-10-Palestinians-reject-2-state-solution-survey-finds).

Why?

Comment: Do Palestinians **really** only accept a 1 state solution?

Comment: By a one state solution, do you mean a unitary state or a federation ?

Comment: Is this even answerable without a given definition of the Palestinian popular consciousness? As I imagine opinions on the matter are not homogeneous amongst Palestinians.

Comment: @LateralFractal the opinions aren't homogenous, but nevertheless, there have been polls and things.

Comment: @Avi Ok. Although I'm tempted to have the title of the question as _"Why do Palestinians that want a one state solution want it?"_

Comment: @LateralFractal Well, as the poll data indicate that most Palestinians want a one-state solution, and as the actions of their governments are consistent with wanting a one-state solution, I think this question's title is reasonable.

also, those are arguably two different questions. One is asking why there is a majority of Palestinians who want a one state solution, and the other is asking why that majority wants it. One is personal motivations, the other is political.

Comment: Unless hard data can be found this question will just get speculations a answers. However I think that the ever expanding settlements have made the two-state solution impossible and that only leaves the one state solution as the only option left.

Comment: @LateralFractal The Palestinian lady I spoke to was very clear she supports a one state solution only, and implied that is the majority position.

Comment: @Vincent I'm not clear myself what exactly Palestinians mean by one state solution, and I'm almost afraid to write this, but from talking to one it would appear they want to see the Jews deported.

Comment: @SamIamsaysReinstateMonica "from the river to the sea" seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: @JohnWoo The American lady I talked to the other day was very clear that she supported Evangelical Christianity being the official religion of the U.S., and promoted in public education, and she too implied that was a majority position.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The Palestinians ultimately want a one state solution because they believe, and have believed for a long time, that all land West of the Jordan river rightfully belongs to them. This been the Palestinian stance since before Israel existed. In 1937, Awni Bey Aboulhadi, Palestinian representative, said before the [Peel Commission](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peel_Commission):

> Every Arab in Palestine will do everything in his power to crush down Zionism, because Arabism and Zionism can never be united together. *(Routledge Atlas of the Arab-Israeli Conflict)*

Similarly, Arabs rejected the [UN's partition plan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Partition_Plan_for_Palestine#Arabs) in 1947 to create a Jewish and an Arab state in British mandatory Palestine because they opposed the creation of any Jewish state. Though the Palestinian Liberation Organization agreed to a [two-state solution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oslo_Accords) in the Oslo Accords, as you pointed out, a two-state solution remains [unpopular](http://www.jpost.com/Diplomacy-and-Politics/6-in-10-Palestinians-reject-2-state-solution-survey-finds) among Palestinians except as an interim to one state.

Even after the creation of the state of Israel, Palestinians have been taught that all land west of the Jordan river (including the West Bank, Gaza, and Israel) belongs to them. Even throughout the 1990s, textbooks used in UN-run Palestinian schools were [explicitly anti-Semitic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_Relief_and_Works_Agency_for_Palestine_Refugees_in_the_Near_East#Criticism_and_controversies), and though there has been some improvement, many Palestinians are still taught with maps failing to depict Israel at all, and with material that denies any historical Jewish connection to Israel.

The Israel/Palestine Center for Research and Information found the following in their 2004 investigation of UNRWA textbooks:

> The practice of 'appropriating' sites, areas, localities, geographic regions, etc. inside the territory of the State of Israel as Palestine/Palestinian observed in our previous review, remains a feature of the newly published textbooks (4th and 9th Grade) laying substantive grounds to the contention that the Palestinian Authority did not in fact recognize Israel as the State of the Jewish people.
>
> ...
>
> The Jewish connection to the region, in general, and the Holy Land, in particular, is virtually missing. This lack of reference is perceived as tantamount to a denial of such a connection, although no direct evidence is found for such a denial." It also notes that "terms and passages used to describe some historical events are sometimes offensive in nature and could be construed as reflecting hatred of and discrimination against Jews and Judaism."

This failure to recognize Jewish history often manifests as [temple denial](http://books.google.com/books?id=mrd8AgAAQBAJ&pg=PA24&lpg=PA24&dq=percent+palestinians+believe+temple+denial&source=bl&ots=4nMIeDmA43&sig=If1DElT_wLNI0kvGwqwvOT0bLj4&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GbJJVPPeBML_iQLc5YGgDw&ved=0CCAQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=percent%20palestinians%20believe%20temple%20denial&f=false), in which Palestinians do not recognize that the second Temple is buried in Jerusalem. A failure to recognize a Jewish connection to Israel contributes to the belief that Israel is rightfully Palestinian land, which is why Palestinians tend to prefer a single state encompassing all land west of the Jordan river.

Comment: It should be noted that the lack of proper border identification appears on both sides: "76% of Israeli textbook maps fail to distinguish the Palestinian territories and Israel, and the Palestinian areas lack labelling, implying that the Palestinian areas form part of Israel." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palestinian_textbooks#2013_Textbook_Study) and that the official stance of the PLO is in favor of a two-state solution.

Comment: @user45891 I did mention that the PLO is in favor of a two-state solution. The statistics on Israeli textbooks are concerning, but I felt not as relevant to my answer. In general, that section of the wikipedia article is an interesting read

Comment: You're right, I confused your answer with something? I'm not sure probably it was in another question. That's what I get for just leaving tabs open.

Comment: Hrm... what to make of this map then: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/81684/is-it-true-that-a-few-days-before-the-current-gaza-war-netanyahu-in-the-un-show

Answer (score 11):

More than [half of all Palestinians](http://www.unrwa.org/sites/default/files/unrwa_in_figures_2015.pdf) live as refugees scattered in
camps and other places around the world. An [overwhelming majority of
them](http://www.wrmea.org/2003-september/poll-shows-right-of-return-a-win-win-situation-for-palestinians-and-israelis-alike.html) wish to return.

Most of these refugees either fled their homes or were forcibly
removed from them by Jewish forces in the [1948 Palestine
war](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1948_Palestine_war). Following the war, they were prevented from returning and
classified as "absentees". Their property, "absentee property", was
was [confiscated by the Israel](https://www.nrc.no/globalassets/pdf/reports/the-absentee-property-law-and-its-implementation-in-east-jerusalem.pdf) and transferred to Jewish
settlers.

In 1973, Israel enacted the [Absentees’ Property (Compensation)
Law](https://www.nrc.no/globalassets/pdf/reports/the-absentee-property-law-and-its-implementation-in-east-jerusalem.pdf) which, in certain cases, allowed "absentees" to claim
compensation for seized property (though not allowing them to reclaim
ownership of the property). However, the compensation paid for
confiscated property was [unreasonably low](https://scholarship.law.vanderbilt.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1687&context=vjtl) and only Palestinians
living in Israel ("present absentees") were allowed to claim
compensation. Moreover, the law only gave a [15 year time
window](https://www.nrc.no/globalassets/pdf/reports/the-absentee-property-law-and-its-implementation-in-east-jerusalem.pdf) for filing claims and hence it has been irrelevant since
1988.

Thus, if a Palestinian state was formed on the West Bank and Gaza,
they would be allowed to "return" to that state but not to reclaim the
land and homes they left.

That is why a combined State of Israel/Palestine where Jews and
Palestinians have equal rights would be much preferable to them. In
contrast, that option is undesirable to Israeli Jews as the State of
Israel/Palestine wouldn't have a Jewish majority. They believe that
current and historical antisemitism teaches them that it is much
better to belong to a country's majority than minority.

Comment: Palestinians today can claim & receive compensation for properties they left in 1948; if feasible, they will receive Israeli recognition of their property rights. [The Palestinian claim to a right of return](https://www.camera.org/article/backgrounder-the-palestinian-claim-to-a-right-of-return/) - "Israeli compensation to Arabs who lost property" And both Palestinian political entities demonstrate quite clearly what "Palestinians & Jews having equal rights" means to Palestinians - no rights for Jews, few rights for Palestinians.

Comment: The law you refer to is not on the books anymore. Regarding your CAMERA quote, see [this skeptics question](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/56685/how-much-compensation-has-been-paid-to-arabs-who-lost-property-in-israel).