# Is it true that a few days before the current Gaza war, Netanyahu in the UN showed a map of the region without Gaza, calling it "The New Middle East"?

Tags: israel, gaza

Many sources show this map, is this true or the map meant something else?

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what this question is asking, if it is indeed a good faith question. The map shows both Gaza and the West Bank, but as part of Israel. What would "something else" mean in this context?

Comment: And Gaza is extremely small as well (which isn't, quite, complimenting Israel).  So showing it off separately would serve what purpose exactly?  Not like Israel has really been riding high on 2 state solutions lately, has it?  So why exactly would you expect this to be any different?

Comment: I guess this is based on some conspiracy theory that Israel was really behind the attacks to give it an excuse to attack Palestine? I am not sure what would make people think that, to be honest: Hamas has not been shy about taking credit for the attack.

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica West Bank is also not shown even though it is bigger.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean "without Gaza". It seems to shows Israel incorporating Gaza, which is in line with the one-state policy Netanyahu governments have been pursuing for a while.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure what you mean by "a map of the region without Gaza". It seems to show Israel *incorporating* Gaza, which is in line with the one-state policy Netanyahu governments have been pursuing [for a while](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/09/10/world/middleeast/jordan-valley-israel-netanyahu.html). Al-Jazeera [agrees](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2023/9/22/palestinians-must-not-have-veto-over-arab-israel-deals-netanyahu-tells-un) with my old eyes:

> Both maps showed the occupied Palestinian territories – the West Bank and Gaza – as well as Syria’s occupied Golan Heights as being part of Israel.

And of course, the Palestinian Authority [disapproved](https://www.timesofisrael.com/liveblog_entry/netanyahu-brandishes-map-of-israel-that-includes-west-bank-and-gaza-at-un-speech/):

> Palestinian Ambassador to Germany Laith Arafeh calls out Prime Minister Benjamin Netanyahu for brandishing a map of the Middle East in his UNGA speech that showed the West Bank and Gaza as part of Israel.
>
> “No greater insult to every foundational principle of the United Nations than seeing Netanyahu display before the UNGA a ‘map of Israel’ that straddles the entire land from the river to the sea, negating Palestine and its people, then attempting to spin the audience with rhetoric about ‘peace’ in the region, all the while entrenching the longest ongoing belligerent occupation in today’s world,” Arafeh tweets.

as [did](https://www.newarab.com/news/pa-thanks-germany-netanyahu-greater-israel-map-spurn) a few other governments.

> "Showing a map that does not depict territories that are occupied or annexed, so to speak, is something that we naturally reject and that is of no help with regard to the efforts to reach a negotiated two-state solution," German Foreign Ministry spokesperson Sebastian Fischer said. [...]
>
> US Department of State spokesperson Matthew Miller also reaffirmed Washington's support for a two-state solution.
>
> "I'm not going to get into any discussion about the map that the prime minister chose to use. I will say that the President has been clear that the United States will continue to support a two-state solution," Miller told journalists.

Comment: I'm not sure if Hamas themselves have said anything about that event. Their long-standing position [is](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2017/5/2/hamas-accepts-palestinian-state-with-1967-borders) to not recognize Israel. But Qatar's government (where some Hamas leaders are located, IIRC) also blasted Netanyahu on that occasion. https://www.timesofisrael.com/palestinian-officials-fume-after-netanyahu-un-speech-call-address-arrogant-racist/

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it seems to be a photo he showed in his speech at the UN on September 22, 2023. [The Times of Israel has a transcript of the speech with a photo of the same map](https://www.timesofisrael.com/full-text-of-netanyahus-un-address-on-the-cusp-of-historic-saudi-israel-peace/).

The term 'New Middle East' refers to Israel and Saudi Arabia's improved relations. From [the article / speech transcript](https://www.timesofisrael.com/full-text-of-netanyahus-un-address-on-the-cusp-of-historic-saudi-israel-peace/):

> What a historic change for my country! You see, the Land of Israel is situated on the crossroads between Africa, Asia and Europe. And for centuries, my country was repeatedly invaded by empires passing through it in their campaigns of plunder and conquest elsewhere. But today, as we tear down walls of enmity, Israel can become a bridge of peace and prosperity between these continents.
>
> Peace between Israel and Saudi Arabia will truly create a new Middle East.

It's mentioned in the speech twice more:

> You know, a few years ago I stood here with a red marker to show the curse, a great curse, the curse of a nuclear Iran. But today, I bring this marker to show a great blessing. The blessing of a new Middle East, between Israel, Saudi Arabia and our other neighbors.

Almost at the end of the speech:

> Let us bring forth the blessings of a new Middle East that will transform lands once ridden with conflict and chaos into fields of prosperity and peace.