# Civil rights of Lebanese Palestinians

Tags: israel, middle-east, civil-rights, refugees, lebanon

What is the position of American and European civil right groups on the situation of Palestinians in Lebanon?

From the Wikipedia article [Palestinians in Lebanon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palestinians_in_Lebanon):

> Most Palestinians in Lebanon do not have Lebanese citizenship and therefore do not have Lebanese identity cards, which would entitle them to government services, such as health and education. They are also legally barred from owning property or entering a list of desirable occupations. Employment requires a government-issued work permit, and, according to the New York Times in 2011, although "Lebanon hands out and renews hundreds of thousands of work permits every year to people from Africa, Asia and other Arab countries... until now, only a handful have been given" to Palestinians. Palestinians in Lebanon also have to heavily rely on the UNRWA for basic services such as healthcare and education, because they are not granted much access to the social services the Lebanese government provides.

An immigrant minority treated in this way would be typically viewed as a case of blatant discrimination, but in the case of Lebanon it seems to be overshadowed by the origin of this population - the descendants of [the Palestinian refugees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palestinian_refugees) from the territories nowadays considered parts of Israel. However, these are two distinct issues:

- It is fair to demand from Israel restitution of property and perhaps even citizenship rights, as this is done, e.g., by many European countries in respect to the descendants of the Jewish refugees from the Holocaust or even the Inquisition. (Possibly, such measures could be installed for Palestinians alongside the similar reparations by the Arab countries towards their Jewish refugees.)
- It is also fair to demand from Lebanon to integrate its Palestinian population - particularly in view of seemingly pro-Palestinian stance adopted by such an influential force in Lebanon as Hezbollah. It is somewhat hypocritical to tell people, who were born in Lebanon and lived all their life in it, that their home is elsewhere.

Comment: I have not heard anything on this topic, from either pro-Palestinian activists or Palestinians themselves. The treatment of Arab refugees in Arab countries seems to be much worse than the treatment of Jewish refugees in Israel. I am not sure about the root causes of this difference. Certainly, many Arab countries are much better off the the Palestinian refugees. Some are exceedingly have many resources, such as the Arab countries in the Gulf region. Given their pro-Palestinian position, it is only reasonable to expect them to offer path to citizenship and decent housing to the Palestinians!

Comment: Related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/81891/why-is-the-palestinian-question-always-framed-in-terms-of-the-palestinian-state

Comment: Important to note the root cause of this problem: Arab League Resolution #1547 March/9/1959, asks Arab countries not to grant citizenship to Palestinian "refugees", in order to preserve the Palestinian "nationality" of the "refugees".

Comment: @Jacob3 even then Lebanon is in violation of the [Casablanca protocol](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casablanca_Protocol)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its just another question pushing a side.

Comment: @JamesK please be more specific: just calling it a push question doesn't make it one.

Comment: The first question I'd ask: is Lebanon actually controlling these areas, or is that just lines on a map?

Comment: @SimonRichter I think it is meaningless to talk about inabilty to enforce policy, if the policy does not exist in the first place. Furthermore, if the Lebanese government does not control certain areas, it is because these are controlled by Hezbollah - who literally claims to do fighting on the Palestinian side

Comment: Yes, but Hezbollah cannot issue Lebanese documents -- that's why the opposite is also true: if a policy exists, it cannot be enforced, and we're unable to tell the difference from the outside.

Comment: @SimonRichter the rights of the Palestinians (or the lack thereof) under the lebanese law is jot exactly a secret - see, e.g., the Wikipedia article linked in the OP. Like in South Africa - *Grand Apartheid* was a legal system, known to everyone, while *petty Apartheid* refers to everyday abuses that are hard to trace.

Comment: @RogerV.  All questions on Israel are now push questions.  Nobody is actually inquiring anymore, this and all the pro-gaza stuff is all just people engaging in whataboutism and making a point.

Answer (score 5):

"American and European civil right groups" is rather broad. [Amnesty International](https://www.amnesty.org/en/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/mde180052006en.pdf) and [Human Rights Watch](https://www.hrw.org/world-report/2023/country-chapters/lebanon#:%7E:text=In%20addition%2C%20there%20are%20approximately,to%20work%20and%20own%20property.) have been critical of Lebanon's policy vis-a-vis the Palestinians. Other civil rights groups, like the [BDS movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boycott,_Divestment_and_Sanctions) or [Students for Justice in Palestine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Students_for_Justice_in_Palestine), are in favour of a one-state solution with a right of return for the Palestinian refugees. This is their solution to the refugee problem, not integration into other Arab states. You claim that this constitutes hypocrisy but I do not see how. In general, in any refugee situation, the default assumption is that the refugees ultimately leave back to their homeland once the political or military crisis in said homeland is resolved. Providing refugees citizenship is exceptional. Lebanon generally does not provide citizenship to Syrian refugees either, for instance.

Comment: What is the homeland of people born into 3rd or 4th generation at specific country?

Comment: @dEmigOd Is it not the Israeli claim that the homeland of the Jewish people remained constant hundreds of generations after the fact?

In any case, most Arab countries (indeed, most countries in general) have [Jus sanguinis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jus_sanguinis) citizenship laws, so a few generations passing isn't quite an adequate rationale to award citizenship.

Comment: I'm not sure how Lebanon not giving Palestineans Lebanese passports is worse than Israel not giving Palestineans Israeli passports while not recognizing Palestine.

Comment: *Is it not the Israeli claim that the homeland of the Jewish people remained constant hundreds of generations after the fact* => it's possible for *both* Israel and the Arab countries to be wrong.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 - To be clear, it is *Israel's* intransigence that prevents descendants of Palestinian refugees from living in Israel, and this intransigence persists completely regardless of the Lebanese nationality, or lack thereof, that these refugees enjoy. There are hundreds of thousands of descendants of Palestinians living in countries with the (much more progressive, incidentally) ius solis law, to no one's detriment. Try going to Rashida Tlaib and telling her that her being American contributes to Israeli mistreatment of Palestinians.

Comment: And put her response here if you get one, it should be entertaining.

Comment: @alamar Palestinians in Israel do have Israeli nationality.

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 could you quote the relevant passages? Also, I think BDS and the Students are not relevant here - the generic Wikipedia links say nothing about their position on the Palestinian discrimination by Arabs - these zre organizations that merely use Palestinian cause to promote their agenda vis-à-vis Israel.

Answer (score 2):

Another answer mentions [Amnesty International](https://www.amnesty.org/en/) and [Human Rights Watch](https://www.hrw.org/). I couldn't find a clear statement from HRW, but [the Amnesty addresses the issue very specifically](https://www.amnesty.org/en/wp-content/uploads/2021/08/mde180052006en.pdf):

> Amnesty International continues to urge the Lebanese government to take all necessary steps to end all forms of discrimination, both *de facto* and *de jure*, against Palestinian refugees, including in their enjoyment
> of the right to work and rights at work, the rights to adequate housing, social security and education. The authorities in Lebanon should also, without delay, take all necessary steps to register all non-ID Palestinian
> refugees and to ensure that all Palestinian refugee children are able to fully enjoy their human rights on par with Lebanese children. In this context, Amnesty International calls on the Lebanese authorities to fully
> implement the CRC’s recommendations without delay.

[ReliefWeb](https://reliefweb.int/) shares an article stating that (although it is not clear, ro what extent this view is that of the whole organization, which is a UN subsidary):

> It is time to end this history of discrimination and systematic segregation. Qualified Palestinians should be allowed to practice their professions, especially in fields where they are most needed.
>
> [...]
>
> A country that respects the rights of refugees would be one that respects the rights of its own citizens. As native Lebanese, we are also struggling for our rights too, whether economic, or rights to accountability and justice. Granting basic rights for refugees will diffuse tension between them and the host community, a vital component of peacebuilding.
>
> I believe that a Lebanon that acknowledges refugees' rights would be an even better country for its own citizens. A Lebanon that is "the land of my dreams", to use Safiya's words.

[Minority Rights Groups says](https://minorityrights.org/communities/palestinians-3/):

> Refugees in Lebanon were in a more serious dilemma than those in Syria or Jordan. The government had stated that ‘under no circumstances will Lebanon agree to give Palestinians citizenship’, and spoken of a ‘redistribution’ of refugees, a euphemism for the expulsion of a substantial proportion of refugees. They thus seemed destined to remain without civic rights. Refugees shared with Lebanon a commitment to the right of return, but both parties knew that Israel was unlikely to honour this humanitarian obligation even in part.

More on the issue:
Report by Asylos [*https://www.asylos.eu/lebanon-report*](https://www.asylos.eu/lebanon-report)
RefWorld (Affilated with the UNHRC): [*Lebanon: Treatment of Palestinian refugees, including information on identity documents, mobility rights, property rights, access to social services, education and employment, and living conditions*](https://www.refworld.org/docid/507553bd2.html)
Al Jazeera: [*Palestinians in Lebanon: ‘It’s like living in a prison’*](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2017/12/16/palestinians-in-lebanon-its-like-living-in-a-prison)

Comment: Thank you for the unbiased answer to the original question, complete with useful details and references, and free of irrelevant rants and soapboxing. Unfortunately, answers like this are becoming a rarity on this site. Much appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

The issue is a consequence of the still unsolved peace process and in particular the question of the [Palestinian right of return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palestinian_right_of_return).

A lot of Palestinian refugees are descendants of people who fled during the [Nakba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nakba), i.e. the "violent displacement and dispossession of the Palestinian people": ["During the 1948 Palestine war, around 700,000 Palestinian Arabs or 85% of the total population fled or were expelled from the territory Israel conquered"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_General_Assembly_Resolution_194#Background). Contrary to [the narrative supported by Israel that Palestinians left willingly](https://theintercept.com/2022/11/25/tantura-movie-israel-palestine/), there is increasingly strong evidence that Israeli militias forced Palestinians to leave their homes; there is also evidence of massacres, like [Tantura](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2023/may/25/study-1948-israeli-massacre-tantura-palestinian-village-mass-graves-car-park).

From the point of view of Palestinians and the Arab countries which support them, this injustice is supposed to be repaired by the [right of return](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palestinian_right_of_return). In December 1948, [the UN Resolution 194](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_Nations_General_Assembly_Resolution_194) acknowledged that indigenous people in the territories that Israel conquered were entitled to come back to their homes or to be offered compensation for the loss of their property.

Thus Palestinian refugees were not meant to be integrated in their host country, their refugee status was expected to be temporary. Since Israel is still refusing to fulfill their obligation by them, the country robbing Palestinians of their rights is Israel, not Lebanon. Moreover, [it has been emphasized that Israel is applying a double standard](https://www.theguardian.com/news/2021/may/18/a-jewish-case-for-palestinian-refugee-return): on the one hand, Israel argues for compensating the victims of Nazi Germany during WW2, including for their stolen property; it also supports the right of Jews to return to Israel-Palestine on the basis that they were there 2,000 years ago. But for Palestinians who were there in the 20th century, Israel tells them to just forget about it.

Comment: Should not then compensation to be paid by multiple arab countries to jews refuges be paid to the palestinians, which then stay homelandless forever?

Comment: *the country robbing Palestinians of their rights is Israel, not Lebanon* => it's possible for *both* Lebanon and Israel to rob Palestinians of their rights.

Comment: This reiterates the points already made in the OP, but doesn't address the essence of the issue - the mistreatment of Palestinians by Lebanon.

Comment: @dEmigOd Yes absolutely, they should too. Israel is the first country which caused these tit-for-tat expulsions, so they should start the process.