Have there been any surveys on public opinion toward Gazan refugees in the Middle East, and if so, what do they indicate?
News articles have suggested that the governments of various Middle Eastern countries, and perhaps even their populace, are generally opposed to taking in refugees from the Israeli invasion of Gaza, as indicated by this article with regard to Egypt and Lebanon, among others. In essence, the leadership of these countries, at least, justifies their position by claiming that taking in Gazan refugees would facilitate what they see as Israel's ultimate goal of annexing some or all of the Gaza Strip while expelling Gazans. However, these articles generally lack polling.
This contrasts somewhat to the position in some other countries, such as Canada, where the National Council of Canadian Muslims wants increased admission of Gazan refugees and the general population is more split. Most of the opposition in these countries seems to come more from prejudice or security concerns from more right-leaning individuals, while the surveys suggest that more left-leaning individuals are more in favor.
Of course, things have also changed over the last year, which may affect polling.
On the one hand, Israeli forces took control of the Gaza border crossing in Rafah in May 2024, which might increase people's impression that accepting Gazan refugees would require collaboration with Israel. On the other hand, the  death toll of the conflict has worsened substantially—as of August 2024, the number of reported deaths was over 40,000, with the indirect deaths likely higher, meaning that the risk to refugees remaining in Gaza is substantially higher, which might be expected to have the opposite effect.
Has there been any polling regarding the positions of the general population in Arab countries on admitting Gazan refugees? If so how has the polling changed over the last year?

Not voting either way.  But remember that the neighboring countries already have a lot of "history" with Palestinian refugees.  Look at Jordan or Lebanon.  Kuwait 1991.  Then Hamas is somewhat kindred with the Muslim Brotherhood which is persona non grata in Egypt.  No one might be too willing to say it out loud - sounds much better to give other reasons - but that is likely a massive factor, aside from, yes, aiding Israel in expulsions.  Plus, the region is already full of refugees (Syria).  How much candor n insight you can expect from a poll in these circumstances seems uncertain.

@ItalianPhilosopher - Sure, I agree that concern about the Muslim Brotherhood and normal opposition to immigration are probably larger factors than people would like to admit. But in order to not let my biases influence it too much, in the first paragraph, I only present the declared perspective of some of the regional governments. If people write an answer that gives polls, they are free to contextualize it as they wish, such as by arguing that the results reflect generic anti-immigration sentiment.

That is also why I cut out the sentences talking about the UK and USA: I felt they tilted it too much toward a possible implication of "progressive people in all these other countries are fine with letting in these refugees, so that's the right policy." People will downvote regardless, but I will nonetheless strive to avoid pushing a position in the question.

Related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/81891/why-is-the-palestinian-question-always-framed-in-terms-of-the-palestinian-state. TL;DR: nobody cares about Gazans enough to actually accept them.
